# Add timeout function inside function before return value

Tags: javascript

This code is working fine , but I  need to add something in timeout function before return in firstFunction()

```
function LastFunction(){    
    var answer = firstFunction();   
    console.log(answer) 
}

function firstFunction() {
    //Do something;  
    return somevalue 
}
```

How to add timeout function inside function before return value ?

```
function firstFunction() {
    setTimeout (function(){
       var something = "something here"
    },1000)
    return something 
}
```

Comment: specify 'add somthing to timeout function'

Comment: just print string now

Comment: Are you just asking for a [sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951021/11336762)?

Comment: What you are looking for is `Promise`. What you're asking for does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use Promises.  Your code inside the `setTimeout` will be delayed but everything outside of it will continue to run synchronously.

```
function LastFunction(){    
  firstFunction().then(function(val) {
    console.log(val) 
    return val
  })
}

function firstFunction() {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var something = "something here"
        resolve(something)
    },1000)
  })
  return promise
}
```

Comment: Thanks , You mentioned it synchronously so could you please add option with asynchronously way ? @Mathew

Comment: This is `asynchronous`. Javascript is synchronous but when you call `setTimeout` you're scheduling the function you pass in to be called a later time. To get the value, you can use promises which are also asynchronous to wait for the promise to `resolve`. Then by use `.then` you can access that value.